# How to store date as 1 and month as 1 to mysql database by using c#

Tags: c#

How to store date as "1" and month as "1" to mysql database by using c#,(for example 1-1-1987),i can get year from the variable frdt,so i need to store for example 1-1-frdt.

```
 string frdt = drow1["release_year"].ToString();
```

Comment: i didnt try it yet but try this format `"M-d-yyyy"`

Comment: Can you please provide me  code for that?@kulotskie

Comment: Are you talking about formatting it with C# or to change date time format in mysql as mysql's default datetime format is yyyy-M-d?

Comment: If you're trying to store a date, why are you using a string at all? Use a `Date` field in MySQL and pass it as a `DateTime` in any interaction with the database. Using strings for time data is a bad idea IMO.

Comment: DateTime mydate=new Date("1","1",frdt); string myDateString= mydate.ToString("M-d-yyyy");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would pass it into a `DateTime` object and insert that one into your database

```
string frdt = drow1["release_year"].ToString();
DateTime Result = new DateTime(int.Parse(frdt), 1, 1);
string Command = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (COLUMNNAME) VALUES (@DATEVALUE);"; // TODO
using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    mConnection.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
    {
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEVALUE", Result);
        int RowsAffected = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing a date then it should be stored as a binary date, not as text.  It's hard to tell whether you're doing that or not but you absolutely should.  The fact that you're storing a year, which is a number, in a `string` variable is not encouraging.  You should be storing the year in an `int` and then creating a `DateTime` like so:

```
var myDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
```

where `year` is the `int` containing the year.  You then save that to your database as you would any other data, using a parameter one would hope, e.g.

```
var command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET MyDate = @MyDate WHERE ID = @ID", connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDate", myDate);
```